# How to fix "Program type already present" in gradle?

Tags: java, android

I'm still new at this, still a student. I'm trying to build an app in Android Studio and I don't know where I went wrong adding or removing something in the gradle.

I've checked many different StackOverflow questions relating to this error, but the answers are all specific to certain libraries.

From other StackOverflow answers, I've gathered that it has something to do with my gradle file. So, here's app/build.gradle:

```
    `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.jaaay.firebaseregister"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libassmidi.so'
            pickFirst 'lib/x86/libassmidi.so'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        }
    }

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/CircleImageView-master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/Android-Image-Cropper-master/gradle/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

This is the issue:

```
Program type already present: org.gradle.cli.CommandLineOption
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.gradle.cli.CommandLineOption, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Comment: comment `CircleImageView` and `Android-Image-Cropper-master` implementations and see if the error still exist.

Comment: @payam No sir, it will input another error. "Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub"